# How to Refresh my Telrik grid or page before or after Response.END

Tags: c#, .net, httpresponse

I have a telerik grid with download column, A user can download a file by clicking on download.
After Download i Want the grid to refresh so that i can change the status of the downloaded file.
But due to Response.end which is used for download, I am not able to refresh the grid even if i bind the grid before response.end...

So is there any work around to refresh page when downloading..

Waiting for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you perform a download the file content is sent in the response and not your page. Hence the short answer is no, you cannot update the page while you are downloading the file. I would recommend when user clicks update the grid and register a script which would perform a another call to the server which will send the file to the client.

Comment: Wot would be the proper way to register a script?

Comment: Use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript which would contain the script required for initiating the download.

Comment: Thanks for the help man.. i guess this should work.. i will apply it now.. :)

Comment: After Applying this i m getting a unique problem.. When i click download for two files it doesnt work.. after that if i click download for the 3rd time or henceforth.. download works fine..

Comment: Use fiddler / firebug to see your second request for download is sent and server is handling fine